# Directive isolated scope initialized from injected service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It have to be smth simple, but so far I can't get it.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uXL95/)

Imaging you have a directive with isolated scope and with dependency from your service. Why you can't initialize variable from your service in the place where you declare the scope? But works perfectly fine if you init that field in the controller.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(i18n) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope:{
        i18n:i18n
    },
    template: '<div ng-bind="i18n(\'myString\')"></div>',
    controller: function($scope){
        //$scope.i18n = i18n //it works if you put it here
    }
  };
});
```

i18n is just local variable for the function where I return an object. It's perfectly fine in terms of initialize the object from variable...so is it some kind of angular restriction and related to possibility to bind data through '@','='... or what?
Could someone shed the light on this matter for me...

Comment: Why do you not want to bind in the controller? The `scope` option for the directive is used to values passed in to the directive via the template.

Comment: this is not what I don't want. Of cause I'll do the way it works. Just was curious  why it doesn't work in a way I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to [The Comprehensive Directive API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) page from Angular Docs:

> #### Scope
>
> - If set to true, then a new scope will be created for this directive. (...)
> - If set to {} (object hash), then a new "isolate" scope is created. (...)
>
>   - @ or @attr - bind a local scope property to the value of DOM attribute. (...)
>   - = or =attr - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value of the attr attribute. (...)
>   - & or &attr - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope. (...)

In other words, this is not what the `scope` attribute of the directive definition object is meant for. It is not a definition of the scope itself, but determines if the directive has an isolate scope, and if so how it links to its parent scope.

The best solution would be as you already suggested, to attach `i18n` to the scope in the `controller` or `link` function.

Answer (score 1):

As you said setting `$scope.i18n = i18n` is the way to go. You cannot use the scope parameter of a directive to inject a service.

Here is a demonstration on how to inject services into directives. I cleaned up your code a litte bit:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uXL95/1/)

This solution will not work after code minifcation. Here is an extended example which will also work minified:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uXL95/3/)

Comment: 1 demo : I purposely made i18n as a function and added .t as a part of an function object(in js function is a callable object). This way it shorter in use and doesn't make it less readable; 2 demo: I know, that was just a demo.  But anyway thx. +1

Comment: Ok, i agree that readability is better with the shorter notation in templates. But I also think that `{{foo}}` is prettier than `ng-bind`

Comment: why? if you have slow internet than before angular bootstap your users will see {{foo}} in their markup. With ng-bind they wont see that ever.

Comment: This can be prevented if you import your angular scriptfiles in the head of your html instead of at the bottom of the body.

Comment: it doesn't matter. Angular can't bootstrap to the container you have for your application if container is not loaded yet. So bootstrap have to be called ether by angular itself or manually only after document is loaded. And not to mansion those cases when you do need to bootstrap angular app manually in a very specific time.